# Trim Loaded Video

Tags: android, android-intent, video, trim

Here is code that helps me to load an external video to a videoView. When I click a button to start Trim intent for loaded video Trim intent starts but send me error message of

> Can't play this video

Thanks in advance for any contribution...

```js
 public void clickLoadVideoToView(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("video/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"),PICK_FROM_GALLERY);

    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY)
            {
                selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                videoView.setVideoURI(selectedImageUri);
                videoView.start();
            }
        }
    }

    public void clickToTrimLoadedVideo(View view) {

        Intent trimVideoIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.TRIM");
        trimVideoIntent.putExtra("media-item-path",pf.getRealPathFromURI_API19(MainActivity.this,selectedImageUri));
        trimVideoIntent.setData(selectedImageUri);
        List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(trimVideoIntent, 0);
        if (null != list && list.size() > 0) {
            startActivity(trimVideoIntent); // Fires TrimVideo activity into being active
        }

    }
```

Following is the class that I use to get real path of The loaded video uri

```js
public class pathFinder {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(Context context, Uri uri){
        String filePath = "";
        String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

        // Split at colon, use second item in the array
        String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

        String[] column = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };

        // where id is equal to
        String sel = MediaStore.Video.Media._ID + "=?";

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return filePath;
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
        String result = null;

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
                context,
                contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

        if(cursor != null){
            int column_index =
                    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(Context context, Uri contentUri){
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index
                = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since your code will not work on very many Android devices, why are you bothering? Few devices will have an app supporting `com.android.camera.action.TRIM`. Fewer still will support your *awful* code for trying to derive a "real path" from a `Uri` that may have nothing to do with `MediaStore`.

Comment: I try to find an easy way to trim videos since mp4parser and and ffmpeg are hard for me to use. Also I tried alot of path finders this one is the only works